# How can I highlight paragraphs by adding a symbol to the left of them?

Tags: paragraphs, highlighting, text-decorations

I would like to add a triangle to highlight important paragraphs in my document. Especially, the triangle should not change the existing text flow.

Example before:

```
   Paragraph one.
   Paragraph two.
   Paragraph three.
```

Example after:

```
   Paragraph one.
|> Paragraph two.
   Paragraph three.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\newcommand{\warn}{\leavevmode\llap{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\Large\color{Crimson}\lefthand}\hspace{\parindent}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

\warn \lipsum[11]

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works well with text paragraphs. I would also like to highlight subsection headlines the same way. In this case, the arrow is shown above the headline. Is this something that could be supported easily or should I open a new question for that?

Comment: Do you want to highlight every subsection headlines, or only some of them?

Comment: Just some of them. It actually seems to work fine if I add `\warn` inside the section command, but I was wondering if it's possible to specify it before the `\section{}` to keep it more readable. If not, I can also create a `\warnsection` command.

Comment: You might define some `\warnsection` command, which incorporates the `\warn` command, and uses the optional argument of `section` for the header and the table of contents.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

**edit** (consider your comments below): for heightening paragraphs always on the left side of paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\attention}{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\vartriangleright$\hspace{\parindent}\quad}} % <---

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\attention\lipsum[11]

\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's great. How to get the triangle on the left side of the text?

Comment: it is simple to have it on outside of text of two side pages (on the left on the even page and on the right right on the odd page). is this what you like to have?

Comment: In my case all pages should have it on the left, since it's a digital document. But it may be possible to set that information globally for LaTeX.

Comment: I figured out how to put the symbol on the other side using `\reversemarginpar`. One little problem is that the symbols are a bit lower for paragraphs that directly follow a section headline. Do you have any idea what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: meanwhile i change solution: i accommodate to your wish that triangle be always on the left side. now is better aligned to first paragraph line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just tried that and the offset is the same independent of any section headers. Now the symbols are taking up space between highlighted paragraph and the one above though.

Comment: Update: The space only occurs when decorating subsection headers that directly follow section headers, it works well for paragraphs. As mentioned in my comment for the other answer, do you think I should open a new question about this or is that easy to support?

Comment: it is better to ask new question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help! I was able to figure it out from the two answers.